# Suggestion required regarding designing a layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

I have to load 3 imageviews per row in my application. I need to do this dynamically through an adapter class. What is the best way of doing this? Which layout should I use?

Comment: Why dont you just use a custom [listview](http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-listview-with-iconsimages-and-sharks-with-lasers/)?

Comment: How many entries of data you have?

Comment: as of now 6.  3 imageviews per row - ie; 2 rows with 3 imageviews

Comment: Then no need of List View , use Table Layout inside Scroll View

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Lazy Loading Listview for that, Below both links for that and change into XML file and set Three(3) Imageview instead of One(1) Textview and One(1) Imageview.

[Lazy Loading Listview](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList)

[Universal ImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Comment: As per @user1400538 he is having only 6 rows it seems so no need of List View , instead Scroll view with Table Layout is more than enough for efficient programming

Comment: is dynamic loading of data possible with the approach you suggest, Venky? so that In future if I have more imageviews, I need not modify the basic design?

Comment: @user1400538 yes its for dynamic loading of data.

Comment: @DipakKeshariya you refer to the samples you provided, correct? and not table layout.

Comment: yes i am using this samples code in my application also and Lazy loading listview example is only for listview and universal image loader example is for gridview, listview and flipper.